# How to download the whole directory of an ensembl FTP page?

Tags: ensembl, data-download

I am interested in downloading all the files at:

ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-91/embl/bos_taurus/

I know how to download a single file from that page using wget (Unix) or download.file() (R) but is there an easy way of downloading all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the mirroring function of wget:

```
wget -m ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-91/embl/bos_taurus/
```